ImportError: cannot import name 'float' from 'numpy': A problem with abydos
I am using a library that requires abydos/distance/_aline.py to be imported. But as can be seen from the source code, it uses the old np_float:
25 from numpy import float as np_float

which throws an error
ImportError: cannot import name 'float' from 'numpy' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py)

I have seen this error before with old versions of packages, so upgrading them usually solves it. This is from the latest installation of the library (abydos==0.5.0). I don't really want to downgrade my numpy installation. Is there a way to get around this?

You could modify the code of abydos.

Probably not. I don't think it could be monkey-patched or any other hack

Can you give the full traceback? I'm curious what the library is using the numpy float for

In the file I pointed out, it is used in only one line s_mat = np_zeros((src_len + 1, tar_len + 1), dtype=np_float)

You can check out the documentation I linked, it seems to be an issue with multiple modules in the library

Found a github issue from abydos right after posting this. Installing v0.6.0b from source solves the issue:
!pip install git+https://github.com/chrislit/abydos.git

Hope this helps anyone trying to use the library. The 0.5.0 version requirement seems to be everywhere.
